# Issue with components drawing on the screen using the Graphics class

Tags: java

I apologize in advance, this issue it sort of hard to explain as I am a beginner.

Anyway, I'm using the Graphics class in java to draw rectangles and such on the application. Here is what is supposed to display: [image] 
It's been working perfectly fine for me and a few of my friends. However, for some of my friends it does not work - but instead, displays this:

https://gyazo.com/ffcced66a915f158184030cc2339d888 (It keeps refreshing and redrawing the gray rectangle)
(Sorry for gyazo gif)

This is the code I am using to draw the rectangles:

```
    static Image selectionImage;

    if (selectionImage == null) {
        selectionImage = createImage(765, 503);
    }

    Graphics graphics = selectionImage.getGraphics();

    graphics.setColor(Color.black);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 765, 503);

    graphics.setColor(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, .1f));
    graphics.fillRoundRect(50, 40, 660, 428, 5, 5); // Background

    graphics.setColor(Color.gray);
    graphics.drawRoundRect(49, 39, 661, 429, 5, 5); // Background
```

I have noticed that it usually doesn't work for people who have the latest version of java (I'm not sure if this could have anything to do with it, surely it could).

So my question to you... What could be something that is causing this? and would java version affect what is drawn on the screen?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. I apologize for any confusion, I'm still a beginner :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the full code you're providing us; it would cause an error since you never set `graphics` to any specific `Graphics` instance.

Comment: Apologies, I just added it in there as an example. Updated the original post

Comment: Could be the fact that you're not preparing the `Graphics` context properly or you've broken the paint chain or you've used a alpha based color for the component background. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Not sure why you are using the getGraphics() method of an Image. If you want to display an image then use a JLabel. `I'm using the Graphics class in java to draw rectangles` -typically  you would do custom painting by extending JPanel (or JComponent) and override the paintComponent() method. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) that provide a working example of drawing a rectangle. I suggest you start with the working code and make your modifications to that code.

Comment: Where is this code place and invoked? Where might `selectionImage` be set? The scrolling effect is a pretty good sign you are drawing directly to `Graphics` associated with the screen and you should be buffering, but it's impossible to tell if that's the only problem (the gif's lines also looks distorted) without more information.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I actually do think it has something to do with drawing an alpha based color. Is there anyway to get around this enabling me to use it?

Comment: 1: Don't use `setBackground` with alpha based colors (`JFrame` exempt); 2: Make the component transparent using `setOpaque`; 3: Fake the transparency using `paintComponent` (don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`)